# Finding Gaussian Mixture Model parameters of colored clusters in pointcloud

Tags: matplotlib, scikit-learn, open3d, gaussian-mixture-model

I am trying to find the Gaussian Mixture Model parameters of each colored cluster in the pointcloud shown below. I understand I can print out the GMM means and covariances of each cluster in the pointcloud, but when I visualize it, the clusters each have a unique color.

How do I find the GMM parameters corresponding to a certain color of a cluster from the pointcloud shown below? Here is my Python code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
import open3d as o3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pdb

def load_point_cloud(file_path):
    pc = None
    pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(file_path)
    pcd_points = np.asarray(pcd.points)
    pcd_colors = np.asarray(pcd.colors)
    pc = np.concatenate([pcd_points, pcd_colors], axis=1)

    return pcd_points, pcd_colors, pc

def coords_to_pcl(coordarray):
    xyz = coordarray[0:None, 0:3]
    rgb = coordarray[0:None, 3:None]
    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(xyz)
    pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(rgb)

    return pcd

coord = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh().create_coordinate_frame(size=0.25)
pc_xyz,_,_ = load_point_cloud("out.ply")  #returns numpy array

gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=8, random_state=0).fit(pc_xyz)  #Estimate model parameters with the EM algorithm
labels = gmm.predict(pc_xyz)

max_label = labels.max()
print(f"point cloud has {max_label + 1} clusters from GMM")
colors = plt.get_cmap("tab20")(labels / (max_label if max_label > 0 else 1))
colors[labels<0] = 0

pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(pc_xyz)
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors[:,:3])

o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd, coord])
```

[Colored clusters generated from scikit-learn GMM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW00t.png)